# Python - Cannot publish module to PyPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

My problem is that I can't upload my module to PyPI. When I run 
`twine upload dist/easy-email-0.0.1.tar.gz`
I get 
`HTTPError: 400 Client Error: 'Easy-email-0.0.1.tar.gz' is an invalid value for Download-URL. Error: Invalid URI see https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for url: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = 'easy-email',
    packages = ['easy-email'],
    version = '0.0.1',  # Ideally should be same as your GitHub release tag varsion
    description = 'Send emails in python!',
    author = 'myname',
    author_email = 'myemail',
    url = 'https://github.com/marmadukeandbob05/Easy-Email/',
    download_url = 'Easy-Email-0.0.1.tar.gz',
    keywords = ['email', 'gmail'],
    classifiers = [],
)
```

Comment: Maybe like people can downvote also could, at least, explain why with a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `download_url` is invalid, it is not a valid URL. Note that you don't need to set that value *at all* when uploading your installation archive to PyPI, because the download URL is *on PyPI*.

Only set `download_url` when you are going to host your packages *elsewhere*, not on PyPI. You would have to use a full URL, so one that starts with `http://` or `https://`, and `pip` or `easy_install` would then follow that URL from PyPI to find the installation archive. You'd only use the `twine register` to register the metadata and just not use `twine upload` at all.

The error message linked you to the [documentation for the field](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#download-url):

> A string **containing the URL** from which this version of the distribution can be downloaded.

Bold emphasis mine; `Easy-Email-0.0.1.tar.gz` is not a URL. It is merely a filename.

You'd use this when you want people to download the archive from a different host, for example, from GitHub. For example, if the [`requests` project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) wanted people to download the release from GitHub instead of from the PyPI servers, they could use `download_url = 'https://github.com/requests/requests/archive/v2.18.4.tar.gz'`, and then only use `twine register` to put the metadata on PyPI.

Comment: But I haven't specified the download url. How do I do so?

Comment: @marmadukeandbob: you did specify the download URL, with `download_url = 'Easy-Email-0.0.1.tar.gz',`. Remove that entirely, *rebuild your package* (`python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`), then register and upload again.

Comment: When I run "python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel" I get an error. It works fine with "python setup.py sdist". But when I try to upload using twine, I get "Server Response (410): Gone" Error

Comment: @marmadukeandbob: I gave an example rebuild command; if you get an error you don't have wheel support installed, that's fine. Did you try `twine register` first?

Comment: How do I use that?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to PyPI.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Registration is [no longer needed](https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#registering-package-names-metadata). The error you got is because you used `twine register`, I think.

Comment: So what do I do?

Comment: Use [`twine upload dist/*`](https://github.com/pypa/twine#usage) after rebuilding the packages there.

Comment: I got "HTTPError: 410 Client Error: Gone"

Comment: It worked now! I changed the url in the .pypirc file to "upload.pypi.org/legacy/"

Comment: @marmadukeandbob: that does indicate that your version of `twine` is too old. See https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading, and try to upgrade.

Comment: @marmadukeandbob: other than that, congratulations on your successfully publishing your package to PyPI!

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!